# How can I use \setcounter with a value calculated in lua?

Tags: luatex, setcounter

How can I use \setcounter with a value calculated in lua?

I tried something like

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{luacode} % for \luaexec macro

\begin{document}

\newcounter{myresult} \setcounter{myresult}{
   \luaexec{%
       bw = 12345 / (1+0.123)^2
       bw = math.floor(bw + 0.5)
       tex.sprint(bw)
   }
}

The result is \themyresult.

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5):

You need something that works by expansion so `luacode` is not helping, `\directlua` works here.

```
\documentclass{article}
%\usepackage{luacode} % for \luaexec macro
\begin{document}
\newcounter{myresult} \setcounter{myresult}{
   \directlua{%
       bw = 12345 / (1+0.123)^2
       bw = math.floor(bw + 0.5)
       tex.sprint(bw)
   }
The result is \themyresult.
}
\end{document}
```